# VPN connection contained within an application

Tags: c#, .net, networking, vpn, cisco

Is it possible to have a program which establishes a VPN connection but the VPN is contained only within the application?

Example:
An application establishes a VPN connection to retrieve the data from another server via VPN without having an effect on the machine's network connectivity - The machine remains on the network/internet as if there is no VPN connection established.

Ideally I'd like to do this in C#.

Also, I currently use a Cisco VPN client which has "Group Authentication" as well an individual user name and password. The C# VPN code I've seen seems to only use the standard username and password so does anyone know if this "Group Authentication" functionality can be implemented in C#?

Comment: That's not VPN, but a secure one-on-one channel. Why don't you just use SSL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I would be connecting to a datacenter via VPN with protocalls and login details that I cannot modify.

Comment: Ondrej is correct, what you describe is not vpn.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything technically impossible about your application creating its own unshared VPN connection to tunnel data across, but that's certainly not the usual use case for a VPN.  A quick Google search didn't turn up any libraries that you might use for this, but you should contact the vendor to see if they have any suggestions.

Comment: So.. how to achieve it?

Comment: What did the VPN vendor say?  You at least need to know what protocols they use.